# How to unproject WKT to WKT in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, coordinate-system, well-known-text

I have WKT in this format:

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POLYGON((491990.250718 6212873.59755,491492.160493 6212904.94117,491265.64715 6212790.54445,491319.517251 6212550.36334,491579.624164 6212637.87553,491611.164518 6212718.61909,492055.359904 6212718.66908,491990.250718 6212873.59755)))
```

It is currently in Euref98 projection and I need it converted to LongLat.

I'm a .NET developer so I prefer a .NET solution.

Is there a .NET library that can parse WKT text into an in-memory model and write the in-memory model back to WKT?

Answer (score 2):

[Proj.Net](http://projnet.codeplex.com/) should be able to do that.

Comment: Proj.NET throws an exception, System.ArgumentException : 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION' is not recognized.

Comment: Looks like Proj.NET only supports SRS WKT syntax, so no geometries. SharpMap should be able to handle WKT geometries, too: http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest class from .NET framework: [DbGeography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
DbGeography dbg = DbGeography.FromText(wkt_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this as well - http://csharp-source.net/open-source/geospatial

Comment: Hi Doug and welcome to GIS.stackexchange! Please summarize the content of the link in your answer. This way, even if the link should break, readers can gain information.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/ WKTReader does the job